# LXR, DXR or woboq for WebKit?

Tags: webkit, lxr

Is there anywhere that you can browse the WebKit source code easily and be able to "go to definition" for information about every variable, type, and function?

Something like the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no), [Mozilla's DXR](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DXR), or [woboq Code Browser](http://code.woboq.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Which specific WebKit port were you interested in? [We](http://woboq.com) managed to get the current Qt5 QtWebKit to compile with the code browser :)

http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebkit/